# Find multiple elements in nested array

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, nested

I Need to find multiple elements in a nested array and return it as an array.

I use the `reduce` function to find the elements, but it returns only one record.

Nested array:

```
{
    "type": "group",
    "level": 0,
    "expand": "-closed",
    "selected": false,
    "text": "Федулов Владислав Владиславович",
    "phoneNumber": "+7 (927) 999 9999",
    "email": "qweeqwe@mail.ru",
    "id": 24,
    "parent": null,
    "cardType": 0,
    "childrens": [
      {
        "type": "group",
        "level": 1,
        "expand": "-closed",
        "selected": false,
        "text": "Ширяев Феликс Богуславович",
        "phoneNumber": "+7 (123) 456 7810",
        "email": "test@test.ru",
        "id": 47,
        "parent": 24,
        "cardType": 0,
        "childrens": [
          {
            "type": "manager",
            "level": 2,
            "expand": "-empty",
            "selected": false,
            "text": "Колесова Анастасия Олеговна",
            "phoneNumber": "+7 (900) 000 0001",
            "email": "eprosvirina@baccasoft.ru",
            "id": 58,
            "parent": 47,
            "cardType": 0,
            "childrens": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "group",
    "level": 0,
    "expand": "-closed",
    "selected": false,
    "text": "Игнатьева Женевьева Павловна",
    "phoneNumber": "+7 (777) 777 7777",
    "email": "igp@sks.ru",
    "id": 3,
    "parent": null,
    "cardType": 0,
    "childrens": [
      {
        "type": "group",
        "level": 1,
        "expand": "-closed",
        "selected": false,
        "text": "Меретин Викентий Васильевич",
        "phoneNumber": "+7 (917) 193 5222",
        "email": "keshman@gmail.com",
        "id": 2,
        "parent": 3,
        "cardType": 1,
        "childrens": [
          {
            "type": "manager",
            "level": 2,
            "expand": "-empty",
            "selected": false,
            "text": "Климаков Алексей Александрович",
            "phoneNumber": "+7 (903) 888 8888",
            "email": "krenog@gmail.com",
            "id": 20,
            "parent": 2,
            "cardType": 1,
            "childrens": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

and the `reduce` function:

```
    var array = store.managersTree.treeNodes;
    var items = [];

    const findItemNested = (arr, searchString, nestingKey) => (
    arr.reduce((a, item) => {
         if (a) return a;
         if (item.text.indexOf(searchString)!==-1 || 
             item.phoneNumber.indexOf(searchString)!==-1 || 
             item.email.indexOf(searchString)!==-1) return item;
         if (item[nestingKey]) return findItemNested(item[nestingKey], 
       searchString, nestingKey)
    }, [])
    );

    const element = findItemNested(array, searchString, "childrens");
```

I am trying to find a record matching at least one criteria, expecting that `reduce` returns multiple records, but this returns only one record, despite there were multiple records found.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPD: `searchString` could be string like `phoneNumber`, `text` or `email`

Comment: Please add the output for a sample `searchString`. Not sure if you want objects from the nested `childrens` included as separate items in the output or just the objects from the main array

Comment: edited the question

Comment: No, I got that the `searchString` could either of those 3 fields by checking the code. Just wanted an output for a sample `searchString`. Like what would be the output for `findItemNested(array, "@gmail.com", "childrens")` Anyway I have added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `reduce` the array recursively.

- [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object in `reduce` parameter to get `nestingKey` and other properties separately
- Create an array of `filterKeys` which have the keys which you want to search for `searchString`.
- Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the fields in the object have a value which [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the `searchString`.
- If `nestingKey` exists, you can push the nested items to the accumulator array.

```js
const input=[{"type":"group","level":0,"expand":"-closed","selected":false,"text":"Федулов Владислав Владиславович","phoneNumber":"+7 (927) 999 9999","email":"qweeqwe@mail.ru","id":24,"parent":null,"cardType":0,"childrens":[{"type":"group","level":1,"expand":"-closed","selected":false,"text":"Ширяев Феликс Богуславович","phoneNumber":"+7 (123) 456 7810","email":"test@test.ru","id":47,"parent":24,"cardType":0,"childrens":[{"type":"manager","level":2,"expand":"-empty","selected":false,"text":"Колесова Анастасия Олеговна","phoneNumber":"+7 (900) 000 0001","email":"eprosvirina@baccasoft.ru","id":58,"parent":47,"cardType":0,"childrens":null}]}]},{"type":"group","level":0,"expand":"-closed","selected":false,"text":"Игнатьева Женевьева Павловна","phoneNumber":"+7 (777) 777 7777","email":"igp@sks.ru","id":3,"parent":null,"cardType":0,"childrens":[{"type":"group","level":1,"expand":"-closed","selected":false,"text":"Меретин Викентий Васильевич","phoneNumber":"+7 (917) 193 5222","email":"keshman@gmail.com","id":2,"parent":3,"cardType":1,"childrens":[{"type":"manager","level":2,"expand":"-empty","selected":false,"text":"Климаков Алексей Александрович","phoneNumber":"+7 (903) 888 8888","email":"krenog@gmail.com","id":20,"parent":2,"cardType":1,"childrens":null}]}]}],
    filterKeys = ["text", "phoneNumber", "email"];

function findItemNested(array, searchString, nestingKey) {
  return array.reduce((acc, { [nestingKey]: nested, ...o }) => {
    if (filterKeys.some(k => o[k] && o[k].includes(searchString)))
      acc.push(o)
      
    if (nested)
      acc.push(...findItemNested(nested, searchString, nestingKey)) 
      
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(findItemNested(input, "keshman", "childrens"))
console.log(findItemNested(input, "@gmail.com", "childrens"))
```

Comment: exactly what i looking for. Now it return matched records with children. Can i filter it to only matched, without children?

Comment: @NastyaKeller updated. You can destructure the `nestingKey` out in the parameter and put the remaining properties in `o`. Now `o` will have every property but `childrens`. And, use `nested` variable in the if condition `if(nested)`

Comment: thank you so much! one more question - what means dots in this line `acc.push(...findItemNested(nested, searchString, nestingKey))`

Comment: @NastyaKeller that's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Since the recursive call to `findItemNested` returns an array, if you `push` it to the accumulator, it will create a 2D array. Let's say: `var a = [1]; var b = [2, 3]` If you do `a.push(b)`, it creates `[1, [2, 3]]`. So, you need to *spread* the array. `a.push(...b)` is similar to `a.push(2, 3)`.

Comment: @NastyaKeller alternatively, you could do `acc = acc.concat(findItemNested(..))` if it's too confusing

Comment: much obliged for answer and explanation:)

Comment: @NastyaKeller Also, `children` is the plural form of `child`. So, `childrens` is not necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Always Array.reduce returns a single value after processing each element in the array. If you want to return matching records in array then you can use, Array.filter,

```
[1,2,3,4,5].filter((element) => {
    return (element === 2 || element ===4);
});
```

For this above code, the filtered array will be,

```
[2,4]
```

And before filter you should either flat the array or should traverse each and every element to filter the array instead of using Array.filter()

Comment: It's `Array.prototype.filter`, there's no `Array.filter`. It's different

Comment: Sorry missed prototype there!

Answer (score 0):

Without reduce also its possible,

```js
var s = [{
    "type": "group",
    "level": 0,
    "expand": "-closed",
    "selected": false,
    "text": "Федулов Владислав Владиславович",
    "phoneNumber": "+7 (927) 999 9999",
    "email": "qweeqwe@mail.ru",
    "id": 24,
    "parent": null,
    "cardType": 0,
    "childrens": [
      {
        "type": "group",
        "level": 1,
        "expand": "-closed",
        "selected": false,
        "text": "Ширяев Феликс Богуславович",
        "phoneNumber": "+7 (123) 456 7810",
        "email": "test@test.ru",
        "id": 47,
        "parent": 24,
        "cardType": 0,
        "childrens": [
          {
            "type": "manager",
            "level": 2,
            "expand": "-empty",
            "selected": false,
            "text": "Колесова Анастасия Олеговна",
            "phoneNumber": "+7 (900) 000 0001",
            "email": "eprosvirina@baccasoft.ru",
            "id": 58,
            "parent": 47,
            "cardType": 0,
            "childrens": null
          },
          {
            "type": "group",
            "level": 2,
            "expand": "-empty",
            "selected": false,
            "text": "Колесова Анастасия Олеговна",
            "phoneNumber": "+7 (900) 000 0001",
            "email": "eprosvirina@baccasoft.ru",
            "id": 534,
            "parent": 47,
            "cardType": 0,
            "childrens": null
          },
          {
            "type": "manager",
            "level": 2,
            "expand": "-empty",
            "selected": false,
            "text": "Колесова Анастасия Олеговна",
            "phoneNumber": "+7 (900) 000 0001",
            "email": "eprosvirina@baccasoft.ru",
            "id": 523,
            "parent": 47,
            "cardType": 0,
            "childrens": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "manager",
    "level": 0,
    "expand": "-closed",
    "selected": false,
    "text": "Игнатьева Женевьева Павловна",
    "phoneNumber": "+7 (777) 777 7777",
    "email": "igp@sks.ru",
    "id": 3,
    "parent": null,
    "cardType": 0,
    "childrens": [
      {
        "type": "group",
        "level": 1,
        "expand": "-closed",
        "selected": false,
        "text": "Меретин Викентий Васильевич",
        "phoneNumber": "+7 (917) 193 5222",
        "email": "keshman@gmail.com",
        "id": 2,
        "parent": 3,
        "cardType": 1,
        "childrens": [
          {
            "type": "manager",
            "level": 2,
            "expand": "-empty",
            "selected": false,
            "text": "Климаков Алексей Александрович",
            "phoneNumber": "+7 (903) 888 8888",
            "email": "krenog@gmail.com",
            "id": 20,
            "parent": 2,
            "cardType": 1,
            "childrens": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }];

  function filterRequiredElement(arr, searchString, nestingKey) {
      arr.forEach((item, index) => {
          if (item.type !== searchString || item.phoneNumber !== searchString || item.email !== searchString) {
             arr.splice(index, 1);
          }
      });
      for(let item of arr) {
          if (item[nestingKey] !== null) {
              filterRequiredElement(item[nestingKey], searchString, nestingKey);
          }
      }
  }

  filterRequiredElement(s ,'Климаков Алексей Александрович', 'childrens');
  console.log(s);
```